# Slice / coslice categories duality

Tags: category-theory

Let $\sf  C$ be a category. Fixed an object $c$, one can construct four categories $\require{AMScd}$ $$\begin{CD} \mathsf C/c @. c/\mathsf C\\ @. @.\\ \mathsf C^{\mathsf op}/c @. c/\mathsf C^{\mathsf op}\end{CD}$$ that are isomorphic (via Yoneda's lemma / embedding),  respectively,  to the comma categories $$\begin{CD} \mathsf C(-,\vee)\downarrow \mathsf C(-,c) @.  (\mathsf C(\vee,-)\downarrow \mathsf C(c,-))^{\mathsf op}\\ @. @.\\ \mathsf C^{\mathsf op}(-,\vee)\downarrow \mathsf C^{\mathsf op}(-,c) @.  (\mathsf C^{\mathsf op}(\vee,-)\downarrow \mathsf C^{\mathsf op}(c,-))^{\mathsf op}\end{CD}$$ So in this square there are various levels of duality: substituting every comma category with its opposite  clearly switches the categories in every diagonal; instead, switching $(\vee,-)$ and $(c,-)$ with $(-,\vee)$ and $(-,c)$ switches the categories column-wise,  and  in fact is the same of switching $\sf C$ and $\sf C^{op}$. Finally, one can also produce a row-wise switch, switching $\vee $ and $c$.

Is there something deeper underlying or charachterizing these reciprocal dualities or they should be taken as they come? For example, the fact that the categories on the diagonal are opposite is also an istance of the fact that the category of elements of a contravariant functor is opposite the category of elements of the same functor considered as covariant from the opposite of its domain; however, it doesn't seem a very useful observation. Thanks in advance for any comment.

*Notation.* I'm denoting with $\mathsf C(-,\vee)=\mathrm y(\vee)$ the covariant Yoneda embedding,  and with $\mathsf C(-,\vee)$ the contravariant one; so $\vee$ is the actual variable, while $-$ doesn't have a role. I defined the comma category $F\downarrow G$ of two contravariant functors $F:\sf D\to C$ and $G:\sf E\to C$ as follows: the object, as usual, are the triples $(d,e,f:Fd\to Ge)$, and an arrow $(d,e,f:Fd\to Ge)\to (d',e',f':Fd'\to Ge')$ is a pair $(h:d'\to d,k:e'\to e)$ such that $f'\circ F(h)=G(k)\circ f$. Thus the comma categories  above are all isomorphic to a slice / coslice category of representables.

Comment: There is nothing particularly deep behind the relations that exist between slices and coslices; maybe the only "formal" point that can be made is how the duality involution $C\mapsto C^{op}$ of $\sf Cat$ interacts with the Yoneda embedding..

Comment: @fosco in the sense that the contravariant embedding $\mathsf C(\vee,-)$, regarded as a covariant functor from $\sf C^{op}$, is $\mathsf{C^{op}}(-,\vee)$?

Comment: I was thinking about the fact that if you call $P$ the functor that acts on objects as $X\mapsto[X^{op},Set]$ and $Q$ the functor $Y\mapsto[Y,Set]^{op}$, then $P$ and $Q$ define each other as $QY=P(Y^{op})^{op}$ and $PX=Q(X^{op})^{op}$, so you have two yoneda embeddings $X\to PX$ and $Y\to QY$ that are interdefinable. As a consequence, yes, representable exchange each other!