# Explanation of an observation regarding Yoneda

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Denote by $\mathsf{CAT}$ the category of all locally small categories, by $\mathsf{Set}$ the category of sets, and write $ [\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{D}]$ for $\mathsf{CAT}(\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{D})$. Also, $\mathrm{op} \colon \mathsf{CAT} \to \mathsf{CAT}$ will be the automorphism $\mathsf{C} \mapsto \mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$.

I cite this fact, that is clear:

> Let $P \colon \mathsf{CAT} \to \mathsf{CAT}$ be the functor defined by $\mathsf{C} \mapsto [\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathsf{Set}]$, and $Q \colon \mathsf{CAT} \to \mathsf{CAT}$ the functor $\mathsf{C} \mapsto [\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{Set}]^{\mathrm{op}}$. There is a commutative square of functors
> $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     \mathsf{CAT}      @>{P}>>  \mathsf{CAT}    \\
>     @VV\mathrm{op}V            @VV\mathrm{op}V \\
>     \mathsf{CAT}      @>{Q}>>  \mathsf{CAT}.
>   \end{CD}
> $$

What I don't understand are two statements following from the observation above:

- *there are two Yoneda embeddings $\mathsf{C} \mapsto P\mathsf{C}$ and $\mathsf{C} \mapsto Q\mathsf{C}$*. What does this mean? The (contravariant) Yoneda embedding of $\mathsf{Set}$ should be $[-, \mathsf{Set}]$, that is different from both $P = [-^{\mathrm{op}},\mathsf{Set}]$ and $Q = [-, \mathsf{Set}]^{\mathrm{op}}$;
- *as a consequence of the commutativity of the square of functors above*, representables switch; i.e., a contravariant functor $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ defined by $C \mapsto \mathsf{C}(-, C)$ is the same as the functor $\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ defined by $C \mapsto \mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}}(C, -)$. Now, the second is a functor in $P\mathsf{Set}$, but the first is not an object of $Q\mathsf{Set}$, because there is no relation between $[\mathsf{C}, \mathsf{Set}]^{\mathrm{op}}$ and contravariant functors $\sf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$. And even if the objects of $Q\mathsf{Set}$ were such contravariant functors, I should have a map $P\mathsf{Set}\to Q\mathsf{Set}$ to put in relations functors $\mathsf{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}$ and contravariant functors $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$; so I'd need more a natural transformation $P \Rightarrow Q$ than a diagram of functors. (I understand that representables switch, I just don't see how it is a consequence of the indented paragraph).

Would someone help me to get a grasp on this? Thanks.

Comment: For any category $A$, there are two embeddings, both of which are from Yoneda: $A \hookrightarrow [A^{op}, SET]$ and $A^{op} \hookrightarrow [A,SET]$. However, the $P$ and $Q$ you have are not the Yoneda embeddings for $CAT$.

Comment: @IsAdisplayName indeed, they are surely not Yoneda embeddings for $CAT$, and not even the image of $Set$ via an embedding. I link the question on MSE where I found these observations (the last comment): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492113/slice-coslice-categories-duality

Comment: What they have written in the comment is different than what you have written: they write that the Yoneda embedding of $A$ is given by the usual functor $A \hookrightarrow PA$ and $A^{op}\hookrightarrow QA$. They simply replace $[A^{op},SET]$ with $PA$. You write that that Yoneda embedding is the functor $P$ (and $Q$, respectively).

Comment: @IsAdisplayName thank you I see a sense now. To be sure: the observation that $PX=Q(X^{op})^{op}$, together with the fact that a functor $C\to D$ is the same as a functor $C^{op}\to D^{op}$, implies that functors $X^{op}\to Q(X^{op})$ are in bijection with $X\to PX$; but it doesn't imply directly that this bijection sends the contravariant yoneda embedding of $X^{op}$ to covariant embedding of $X$ (although it is clearly true). Do you think that this was the sense of the original comment?